# How do I use a dependencies repository for all my projects in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a group of 5 gitlab projects. One of these projects contains files, scripts and dependencies that are necessary for the other projects. The reasoning is that all the projects are going to use these tools so might as well have a single source of truth. In that project, there's a text file that is needed in the testing phase in the pipeline for all the projects. Is there a way to access that file in gitlab-ci.yml ?

I want to clone/copy/access the file in the testing phase of the pipeline.

Comment: GitLab documentation _Store all of your packages in one GitLab project_: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/workflows/project_registry.html

Answer (score 1):

There is little context here, and you do have multiple possibilities to do so.

1. Generate your own Docker image in the first repository, which contains all the data and the necessary tools, and use this in your .gitlab-ci.yml file. Everytime you change something in repo one, just build a new docker image with the changes and the other repositories can use it.
2. use git submodules. You can add the first repository as a submodule to the others, and use this git feature to have the data at hand.
3. checkout those files into an own subfolder during the build with the gitlab token.
4. generate an artifact, which you upload to your generic package registry and you fetch that within you gitlab-ci.yml file.

I am sure there are plenty of other options too, it always is a tradeoff and depends on what is the underlying language/build tool. eg. if you are in java you could also zip that and upload it to the maven package registry and so on.

Based on the information i have, i think all of the mentioned options are viable. I would most likely use the Dockerfile approach if it is just for building. If you want to also have the benefit locally i would suggest to use submodules. But as mentioned it depends on your project setup in general.

Comment: Option 3 seems is similar to what I ended up doing, I'll explain it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was making a call to the gitlab api using the generated tokens as follows:

1. Create a Project Access Token on the first repository (containing the relevant files, dependencies, etc). Make sure the token is for read/write to api.
2. Copy and add the token to the environment variables in the other projects.
3. In the pipeline, use wget or curl to get the files needed:

`wget --header="PRIVATE-TOKEN: $YOUR_TOKEN_HERE" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/repository/files/<encoded-path-to-file>/raw?ref=master"`